# Need Shell script for Linux

Tags: linux

I have file1

```
cat file1
test1
test2
test3
test4

cat file2
test3
test1
test2
```

So `test4` is missing in `file2`.

I want to have a script through while loop that should take `test1` from `file1` and search for `test1` in `file2`. (The order of the file is not the same)
I want an output to show that

```
test4 is missing from file2
```

Comment: What did you try already? Where did you encounter problems? How does the script look so far?

Comment: welcome to U&L, I fixed formating, however,  we are not a script writing service, what have you tried ?

Comment: Why not just use `diff` or `comp`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to sort file1 and file2 first (using the `sort` command).  Then you can use the `join` command.

```
join -a 1 file1 file2
```

output:

```
test4
```

what the `-a 1` command does is print the lines that *do not* match in file1.

man page exert:

```
  -a FILENUM        print unpairable lines coming from file FILENUM, where
                      FILENUM is 1 or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2
```